# In Spring Boot, Can we add @Service Annotation for Interface? if that interface is not implemented by any class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a interface which has not any implementations

```
@Service
public interface MyInterface{


    default void doSomething{
      System.out.print("print something");
    }
}
```

Can MyInterface be annotated by @Autowired?

```
@Autowired
MyInterface myInterFace;
```

following error displayed when it run

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field myInterFace in com.example.demo.controller.corejava.CoreJavaController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.controller.corejava.MyInterface' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Comment: What happens if you try it??

Comment: We can explain it better if you give us some error code. If you want to create your service as an interface, create a class named MyInterfaceImpl and add @Service on that class and implement MyService interface.

Comment: @luk2302,@huseyinkadioglu i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, because Spring tries to instantiate it to create a Bean (@Service), but it's an Interface, so thats not possible.